# EF6 EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am constantly getting EntityCommandExecutionException while executing simple query.
The query occurs in context of transaction and this is usually happens when there are many threads locking some of the database tables.

I use serialized lock and have a retry pattern, although retries work when deadlock occur i cant figure out how to handle this error or why it could be thrown.

```
  Time: 9/26/2016 9:01:53 PM
Message: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 59) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at GizmoDALV2.DefaultDbContext.SaveChanges()
   at ServerService.Service.SessionSetState(Int32 sessionId, SessionState state, DefaultDbContext cx)
   at ServerService.Service.<>c__DisplayClass780_0.<OnProcessUserHostConnect>b__0()
   at GizmoDALV2.DefaultDbContext.RetryBeforeThrow(Action action, Int32 retries, Int32 minWaitTime, Int32 maxWaitTime)
   at GizmoDALV2.DefaultDbContext.RetryBeforeThrow(Action action, Int32 retries, Int32 minWaitTime, Int32 maxWaitTime)
   at ServerService.Service.OnProcessUserHostConnect(HostComputer hostComputer, ClientDispatcher dispatcher)
   at ServerService.Service.OnClientConnection(IConnection sender, Socket socket)
Member name: OnClientConnection
Source file path: D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gizmo\GizmoService\GizmoService\Service\Service_Network.cs
Source line number: 702
```

Any possible causes for this ?

Comment: You have a deadlock (look at exception message). Check your queries, analyze it with SQL Profiler. Read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: hmm actually that is true, it seem that the other errors caused by command timing out.

Comment: one question to see if my understanding is correct. in case a thread holds a lock and there is simple read done (outside of transaction) on the table the reading thread would block until its timeout expires ?

Comment: it depends on isolation level. I think, your level is snapshot or serializable. check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx